# How to determine the Galois group knowing the following

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

Let's suppose I have the polynomial $p$ of degree $n$:

$p(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1x + a_0$

Let's also suppose I have another polynomial $f$ of degree $m$, which their roots $r$ satisfy a linear relation, for instance, the following one:

$r_f = r_{p_n} + r_{p_{n-1}}$

Is there any relation between their groups? Any references on this particular matter?

**EDIT**

I have read this https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348814816_Matrices_and_Galois_Theory and I am attempted to conclude the following. Given a field $P$ an its extension (generated by the roots of $p(x)$) $P(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)$ contains the another extension $P(p_1+p_2, p_1 +p_3, \ldots, p_{n-1}+p_n)$, which turns out to be the field of $f(x)$. Therefore,

$ H = P(p_1+p_2, p_1 +p_3, \ldots, p_{n-1}+p_n) \subseteq P(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n) = P$

Is this reasoning correct? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the linear relation has rational coefficients (of course, any two sets of complex numbers satisfy relations if the coefficients can be arbitrary), then yes, the extension given by $f$ is contained in the extension given by $p$ implying a relationship between Galois group by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. If the relation matrix is invertible, then the extensions are the same, as are the Galois group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know much about Galois Theory. When you mention relation matrix you mean the ones discussed here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348814816_Matrices_and_Galois_Theory ?

Comment: @Mr.N I am referring to the "relations" you mention in the question: Your routs satisfy $R_f =A R_p,$ where $R$ is the vector of roots, and $A$ is the matrix of which I speak.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now I understand which is the matrix. Well, that would happen if and only if $n=m$. I was thinking about proposing the explanation above. Thanks for your answer again